# Invalid context error from inside a drawRect member function

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgcontext

While running an iOS program in XCode 4.6.3, I keep getting a long list of errors like the following:

```
Jul 20 13:24:40 ps2xipas3qfe Chess[277] <Error>: CGContextSetRGBFillColor: invalid context 0x0
Jul 20 13:24:40 ps2xipas3qfe Chess[277] <Error>: CGContextFillRects: invalid context 0x0
```

Here is the code that generates the error:

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect {
    //[super drawRect:rect];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            CGRect TheRect = CGRectMake(i*30+30,j*30+30,30,30);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            if(i%2 == j%2) {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
            else {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
            CGContextFillRect(context,TheRect);
        }
    }
}
```

When I searched for the web for "invalid context" errors, the answers I got were that a graphics context can only be retrieved from within a "drawRect" member function, but this is within a "drawRect" function and I am still getting the error. The class here is `ChessBoard` which inherits from `UIView`.

---

Thanks for the help, but I cannot get my program to run and am very confused. I no longer get the errors that I used to get, but I now only get a blank screen. I tried `setNeedsDisplay` and `setNeedsDisplayInRect` but neither of them seem to work.

Here is a function I have in `ChessViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ChessBoard* TheBoard = [ChessBoard new];
    [self.view addSubview: TheBoard];
    // [TheBoard setNeedsDisplayInRect: CGRectMake(0,0,400,400)];
    [TheBoard setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Here is a function I have in `ChessBoard.m`:

```
- (void)drawRect: (CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    UILabel* HelloWorld = [UILabel new];
    HelloWorld.text = @"Hello, World!";
    [HelloWorld sizeToFit];
    HelloWorld.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,100,20);
    [self addSubview:HelloWorld];
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<8; j++) {
            CGRect TheRect = CGRectMake(i*30+30,j*30+30,30,30);
            CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
            CGContextFillRect(context,TheRect);
            if(i%2 == j%2) {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
            }
            else {
                CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context,0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am explicitly calling `drawRect`. I didn't realize that I was not supposed to.

Comment: Never call `drawRect:`. It even tells you this in the docs for `UIView drawRect:`. If you wish to force a view to draw itself again, call `setNeedsDisplay` on the view. See the duplicate referenced by Josh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is very close! The code you're using to instantiate your ChessBoard instance is incorrect, though. Instead of using "new" (which should always be avoided in Objective-C, anyway), the documentation for UIView points out that you must use the initWithFrame: initializer method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect boardFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 240);
    ChessBoard *theBoard = [[ChessBoard alloc] initWithFrame:boardFrame];
    [self.view addSubview:theBoard];
}
```

If you try that you should see your drawing code working.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That pretty much worked.